# Can't rename multiple files (Python)

Tags: python, rename, glob

I am trying to rename some files but I can't figure it out.

These are the files I want to be renamed:

[image: src]

Their are counted from 13 because there are other imges before but they are deleted (so just these remains)

With this code nothing is done.

```
for (cnt,contours) in cnts:
    idx += 1
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    roi = gray1[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(thresh_color,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    if (w * h >= 180 * 30):
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\FOLDER\\ex_area1') + str(idx) + '.tif', roi)


files = glob.glob(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\FOLDER\\ex_area1') + str(idx) + '.tif')
for file in files:
    parts = file.split('_')
    new_name = 'ex_{}'.format(parts[0])
    os.rename(file, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file),new_name))
```

`idx` is a counter which increment the number by one for every image. It's declared above this code in the program.

How can I rename these "new" images again ?

`ex_area13` and `ex_area14` should be `ex_area11`, `ex_area12` and so on..

Thanks

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: What files contains? Is it empty?

Comment: Vinny, output remains the same, seems like nothing change.

Ivan, files are images, .tif format

Comment: The problem is here: os.rename(file, new_name)

Comment: use 'mv' from bash instead of python. In subprocess package(https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) you can do bash commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this code. It's also ignores errors due to overwrite. For me is working great.

```
try:
    path = (os.path.expanduser('~\\FOLDER\\')) #path to images folder
    files = os.listdir(path)

idx = 0  #counter

for file in files:  #search for files..
        idx =+ 1
        i = 'ex_area1'  #name of the file I search for and which will be renamed
        if file.endswith('.tif'):  #search only for .tif
            i = i + str(idx)  #add to i the i+counter (namefile+counter)
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.tif'))

except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:   #if there are errors of overwrite, ignore them
            raise
```

Comment: hours after research and tests :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
import os

folder = "."
#tif_files = [i for i in os.listdir(folder) if i.endswith(".tif")]
tif_files = ["ex_area13.tif","ex_area14.tif"]

for ind, file in enumerate(tif_files):
    new_name = "ex_area{}.tif".format(str(ind+11).zfill(2)) #11,12... can be changed to 001,002... or other
    oldpath = os.path.join(folder,file)
    newpath = os.path.join(folder,new_name)
    #os.rename(oldpath,newpath)
    print("{} --> {}".format(oldpath,newpath))
```

Prints:

```
./ex_area13.tif --> ./ex_area11.tif
./ex_area14.tif --> ./ex_area11.tif
```

Comment: @Link Looking more carefully at your code some things are just strange. In what folder is it the changes are to be made?

Comment: What do you mean by map ? The names should remain the same except for the last digit which need to increment again. Instead of the actual 13 it should be renamed from 11. BTW, I added more code..

Comment: With the actual (above code) it prints nothing []. If I change the file name and leave just `('\\FOLDER\\*.tif')` it prints the full path to the files

Comment: with your new code, in console the files are ok but they are saved wrong in the folder..

Comment: but the folder = "." should point to the folder where the files are folder = "\\path\\to\\folder"

Comment: yes, I already tried that...now I am looking for something more simple.
I think about this: list all files, take only tif, put a counter, rename them with `ex_area1 + counter`. I'm not sure if it will work...

Comment: @Link How about now, can use str(ind+11) if you want to start with 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156009/discussion-between-anton-vbr-and-link).